# What does J signify on a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I am working on an electric fence energiser and trying to figure out what the issue is. I am testing all of the components and have taken these capacitors out of circuit to measure them. I am unsure what J signifies though as the readings I get on a multimeter don’t seem to align with uf, nf, pf etc when I put it into a conversion page.
To be able to replace them with the same value I need to work out what value j is.

[image]

Comment: how do you know that the component is a capacitor?

Comment: From the look of them and the fact all fencers have them. Plus they give you one hell of a shock when they work.

Comment: What readings do you get with your multimeter? Do they have the same digits as on the components (22 or 11)? What conversion are you trying to do?

Comment: @Barry well the one rated 1j 400 reads 1.033uf the one rated 2.2j 250 reads 50.25nf so presume that’s shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a capacitor, J usually signifies that it has a 5% tolerance: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Capacitor)

So, when the capacitor marking is 2.2 J 250 it usually means 2.2 μF rated with a 5% tolerance capable of withstanding up to 250 volts. To be clear about whether the 250 volts is DC or AC depends on knowledge of the capacitor type.

Comment: So on my capacitors it would be 1.1Uf 5% 250v and 2.2Uf 5% 400v ?

Comment: @IainSimpson Most likely. For some reason capacitors are always either marked in μF or pF, never nF or mF, and these are too big to be pF.

Comment: @IainSimpson you have a 1 uF 400 volt capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

J means the capacitance has a 5% tolerance.